# Triming a php echo for ajax

Tags: php, ajax

The problem i have is with a simple ajax mail script.

I have it working fine like this:

php snippet:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
echo "success";
}
```

And back in the ajax code its handled here :

```
         if($.trim(data) == "success"){
           // do the success stuff
         }else{
           // doo the fail stuff
         }
```

My concern is that in the jquery code "trim" is not supported in all versions of explorer.
So i would rather have the php return the string "success" already trimmed.
But changing things to what you see below does not work as i expected, and runs the fail function in the ajax..?

Ammended php :

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
$success = trim("success");
echo $success;
}
```

Ammended Ajax :

```
     if(data == "success"){
         // do success stuff does not happen anymore
     }else{
         // now it always does fail stuff, so comparison is always false
     }
```

Why is doing the trimming in the php instead of the ajax letting me down please..?

Comment: Isn't jquery optimized to run on almost every browser? Did you have a case where the jquery trim didn't work?

Comment: `console.log` (or `alert`) your `data` and see what is in there? Otherwise: you might want to use JSON to pass your data instead of just plain text?

Comment: Why are you trimming? There doesn't seem to be a need for it.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use a json response?
ex. {response: "success"}

Comment: `if (data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '') === 'success') { //...` or even a prototype `trim()` method for strings: `String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, ''); };` so you can do `if (data.trim() === 'success') { //...`

Comment: Please can we see the full AJAX code?

Comment: jquery trim does fail in some versions of ie. I don't remember of the top of my head which ones. But i have had to provide an altenate function for trim in the past, if certain versions of ie were detected.   I am going to look into the answer below, and may find something there, but i may have to turn to using a json response. I will let you guys know what i find the issue was.. thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the string "success". Trimming just removes spaces and white-characters (newlines, etc.) from the beginning and ending of a string. And in "success" there is no such thing, so it does nothing. However, if trimming *on the JavaScript side* works, then your PHP must be producing some whitespace characters, so it appears in the response. But this is not in the code you posted, there is no problem with the work "success". You have to go through your code and find the source of the newlines/spaces/white characters.

Usually, the problem is with Unicode BOM marks (look that up and open your PHP files in an editor that can show you if they are present or not) or newlines at the end of a PHP file (remove these).

Comment: I thank you for making me realize that white space was being generated elsewhere in the php. What it acctually turned out to be was the fact i had my opening and closing php tags spaced from the left of the file by three spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this...
in ajax

```
$('#err_register').html("Data:"+data+"Display");
var resultData=jQuery.trim(data);

if(resultData == "success"){
         // do success stuff does not happen anymore
}else{
         // now it always does fail stuff, so comparison is always false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery.ajax you can specify success/complete/failure callback functions. Your jquery call could be a function that executes your mail function and then returns true or false. You can then check the return in your success function.

[check it out here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: The problem with that in my case, is i am trying to do 2 different things, depending on what kind of success i get from the php. I need to handle both in the success function in ajax. I echo "success" else echo "semisuccess"

Comment: @Alchemy you could easily write an if or some kind of other check in your success function to check what kind of success you have. After that you can call call the necessary method depending on which success you achieve.